# KDB/Q building a stock market index

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to build a stock index and I'm using Q for the purpose. As you can probably tell, I'm very new at this. Whereas I've built it in SQL, it takes way too long to process, hence my resorting to Q.

The setup so far is the following:

1. The table; add data to the table, sort it:

   ```
   tickers:`ibm`bac`dis`gs`ibm`gs`dis`bac
   pxs:100 50 30 250 110 240 45 48
   dates:2013.05.01 2013.01.05 2013.02.03 2013.02.11 2013.06.17 2013.06.21 2013.04.24 2013.01.06
   sectors:`auto`money`funny`money`auto`money`funny`money
   trades:([sectors;tickers;dates];pxs)
   `sectors`dates`tickers xasc `trades
   ```
2. The processing so far (thanks to other friendly SO users):

   - I've calculated by how much has each stock price changes from the previous time the price was recorded

     ```
     trades: update delta:{0,1_deltas x}pxs by tickers from trades
     ```
   - I've calculated the total market value of the components of the sectorial index

     ```
     trades: update idxmv:sums[?[delta<>0;delta;pxs]] by sectors from trades
     ```
3. How it looks:

   ```
   sectors tickers dates     | pxs delta idxmv
   --------------------------| ---------------
   auto    ibm     2013.05.01| 100 0     100
   auto    ibm     2013.06.17| 110 10    110
   funny   dis     2013.02.03| 30  0     30
   funny   dis     2013.04.24| 45  15    45
   money   bac     2013.01.05| 50  0     50
   money   bac     2013.01.06| 48  -2    48
   money   gs      2013.02.11| 250 0     298
   money   gs      2013.06.21| 240 -10   288
   ```
4. What I want to do:

   I want compute a sector index, that changes when its components change; in order to do this I need to compute a divisor column and the actual index column. The logic I'm trying to implement is as follows:

   - if `delta != 0`, then `divisor = the last value of the divisor, in the same sector`
   - if `delta != 0`, then `index = idxmv % the value of the divisor computed above`
   - if `delta = 0`, then `index = the last value of the index, in the same sector`
   - if `delta = 0`, then `divisor = idxmv % the value of the index computed above`, where the initial value of the index is 100; all the sector have a starting value of the index of 100

So essentially, what I want to end up with, is something similar to the below:

```
    sectors tickers dates     | pxs delta idxmv divisor index
    --------------------------| ------------------------------
    auto    ibm     2013.05.01| 100 0     100   1       100
    auto    ibm     2013.06.17| 110 10    110   1       110
    funny   dis     2013.02.03| 30  0     30    0.30    100
    funny   dis     2013.04.24| 45  15    45    0.30    150
    money   bac     2013.01.05| 50  0     50    0.50    100
    money   bac     2013.01.06| 48  -2    48    0.50    96
    money   gs      2013.02.11| 250 0     298   3.10    96
    money   gs      2013.06.21| 240 -10   288   3.10    92.78
```

Thanks for your help,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

```
trades1:update index:{100f,1_count[x]#0n}[delta] by sectors from trades; / starting value of index as 100  
trades1:update divisor:?[delta=0;idxmv%index;0n] by sectors from trades1;  / divisor=y%z when delta=0  
trades1:update divisor:?[delta<>0;fills divisor;divisor] by sectors from trades1; / divisor=last divisor when delta <> 0  
trades1:update index:?[delta<>0;idxmv%divisor;index] by sectors from trades1; / index=i%d when delta <>0  
trades1:update index:?[delta=0;fills index;index] by sectors from trades1 / index=last index when delta=0  
trades1:update divisor:?[delta=0;idxmv%index;divisor] by sectors from trades1; /divisor=y%z when delta=0
```

This should solve your problem.
The last row doesn't seem to be matching.I have taken sectors as a primary key.You should be able to match the last row by changing the primary key to sectors/tickers.

Comment: Thanks for your help akash. It's way more than I've ever gotten so far. I'm looking into having the last row correctly computed as well, thanks again for pointing out some really useful functions.